# Errors using the try catch block

Tags: java, io, try-catch

I am having some problems when I run this code. It executes the first and second System.out.println just fine. The program then calls IOHelper and it allows me to input a number. Once I enter the value, it prints "Obtained: xxxx" and then prints "Please enter the wind velocity:" followed by this list of errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException    
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)    
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)   
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)   
at Assignment1_14.IOHelper(Assignment1_14.java:49)   
at Assignment1_14.main(Assignment1_14.java:27)
```

I am using eclipse.

```
public class Assignment1_14 {

// declaring constants
final static double GRAVITY = 9.807;
final static double MASS_INITIAL = 0.008;
final static int LAUNCH_VEL = 22;
final static int DENSITY = 1900;
final static double BURN_RATE = 0.003;
final static int MIN_ANGLE = -15;
final static int MAX_ANGLE = 15;
final static int MIN_WIND = -22;
final static int MAX_WIND = 22;

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Hello, in order to launch the Roman Candle, please set \n"
            + "the launch angle and wind velocity. Note, the launch angle must be \n"
            + "between 15 degrees and -15 degrees.\n\n");

    System.out.println("Please enter the launch angle: ");
    double angle = IOHelper(MIN_ANGLE, MAX_ANGLE);
    System.out.println("Obtained: " + angle);

    System.out.println("Please enter the wind velocity: ");
27  double windVel = IOHelper(MIN_WIND, MAX_WIND);
    System.out.println("Obtained: " + windVel);
} // end main method

public static double IOHelper (double low, double high) {
    Scanner screen = new Scanner(System.in);
    double num = 0;
    boolean inputOK = false;
    String dump = null;

    while (!inputOK) {
        try {
    49      num = screen.nextDouble();
            dump = screen.nextLine();

            if (num < low || num > high) {
                inputOK = false;
                continue;
            } // end if statement
            inputOK = true;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            dump = screen.nextLine();
            System.out.println("\"" + dump + "\" is not a legal double, "
            + "please try again!");
        } // end try-catch block
    } // end input loop
    screen.close();
    return num;
} // end IOHelper method
```

Comment: Does that stack trace occurs before you interact as a user with the IOHelper the second time ?

Comment: can write lines with numbers from your stack trace? 49 and 27.

Comment: @Dominik I tried that for line 27 by entering -15 and 15 for the inputs, but line 49 is the num = screen.nextDouble(); and i need that for the user to input data. If that's what you meant

Comment: @OYRM I'm not entirely sure what you are asking

Comment: write it for us dude! how can we know which line is problematic if we do not have numbers? should we count it?

Comment: @Michael No worries, btw, reading the stack trace makes it really clear where the exception gets thrown and so, that's not actually hard to read at all.  Does the NoSuchElementException get thrown before you interact with the screen, or does it wait for you, blocking until you make an entry, then throw the exception ?

Comment: The lines are in, and @OYRM it waits until i make an entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NoSuchElement exception gets thrown because there is no element to read. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29

Either catch it, or add a check for input before you read a token

```
while (!inputOK) {
    try {
        if(!screen.hasNext()) continue;
        num = screen.nextDouble();
....
```

Comment: Thank you it works now! So why did this work though? I read the api but it's still a bit unclear to me

Comment: The API states that `next()` "may block", but does not say that it will block.  So, this means there is some indeterminacy in the implementation.  That sort of thing needs to be controlled for.  My code, with the check on `hasNext()` confirms that there are tokens in the screen before trying to access them.

Comment: This worked for the first call of IOHelper, but I am stuck in an infinite loop in the second call of IOHelper even when i provide input that is between the low and high values. and it continuously lets me enter numbers but never returns back to main to print "Obtained: xxxx"

Comment: I don't mind the second question, but it may be best for you to run the code through a debugger and observe how those checks and loops work.  Are you familiar with the practice of debugging and watching variables ?

Comment: Okay so I got it working, my issue is that the second time it enters IOHelper, screen.hasNext() is true, which means that it will go to false since the ! operator in front, and then it gets to the continue line and starts over. do I need to add a screen.nextLine() anywhere?

Comment: It's a good idea to check for tokens like that when you're using an iterable.  The idea here is that you can guarantee that the code is not fragile